# Is Deadpool from the movie the same character as Wade in X-Men Origins Wolverine?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016, x-men-origins-wolverine

Is the character played by Ryan Reynolds (Wade Wilson) in X-Men Origins: Wolverine the same as the character played by Ryan Reynolds in the upcoming movie Deadpool?

Or is the X-Men Origins: Wolverine movie set in a different universe than the Deadpool movie [The Marvel Cinematic Universe vs. The X-Men Cinematic Universe]?

Comment: Do you mean, is the character played by Ryan Reynolds in *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* the same as the character played by Ryan Reynolds in the upcoming *Deadpool* movie, or if the character he played in *Origins* was meant to be the comic book character Deadpool?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? Even looked at the [Deadpool Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadpool)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're asking if the character of Wade from *X-Men: Origins* is the same character as Deadpool in the upcoming movie *Deadpool*.

To quote from CinemaBlend's [review of the movie's script](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/Deadpool-Script-Review-This-Role-Could-Make-Ryan-Reynolds-An-Icon-21158.html)

> Of course there’s a problem in turning Deadpool into a movie, it’s a problem caused by X-Men Origins: Wolverine where the character was first introduced, abused, ruined, and then killed. This script eliminates that problem brilliantly by, well, mocking it. The script never comes right out and mentions Wolverine, it’s all accomplished through one specific subtle reference, which says everything that needs to be said. It’s as though **the character of Deadpool exists in a world where Wolverine is a movie that he’s seen, and hates.** Deadpool literally throws everything Wolverine did to screw up this character in the trash can, and then spends the rest of the movie endlessly poking fun at the celebrity of Hugh Jackman.

Comment: Of course, I guess that script might not necessary bear precise resemblance to what makes it on-screen.

Comment: @Paul I don't have the quote, but someone involved said that it's 30% different.