# Why would Wolverine be needed to greenlight Deadpool movie?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the opening 4th wall breaking quote of "Deadpool" film, Deadpool tells the audience:

> I know right? You're probably thinking, "Whose balls did I have to fondle **to get my very own movie**"? I can't tell you his name, but it rhymes with "Polverine."

I know the usual explanation is that it's meant as a poke at the studio (and the difficulty of having a solo Deadpool film), but it seems rather weirdly worded for that purpose - **neither Wolverine (the fictional character), nor even the actor playing him (Hugh Jackman) have absolutely any control over which movies get made** - the studio execs decide that, or the producers.

***So what does "Wolverine" have to do with this?***

I'd prefer answers based in canon (canon includes interviews etc...) over speculation.

Comment: Initial assumption: it's an *X-Men Origins* joke; Deadpool had to play second fiddle to Wolverine before he could "earn" a solo outing

Comment: See also: the accepted answer on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110423/is-deadpool-from-the-movie-the-same-character-as-wade-in-x-men-origins-wolverine?rq=1)

Comment: What if there are no answers because it is just a simple joke?

Comment: I was going to mark this off-topic, then realised, as it's Deadpool, and he breaks the fourth wall, it's not off-topic and that's the whole point of the joke.

Comment: Nemolverine is one of big investors of Deadpool movie..

Comment: Honestly we don't know if it was Wolverine that gave the green light... All we know it that it rhymes with "Polverine" (as you said) and "he has some smooth criminals down under"... that could be anyone! Assuming it is Wolverine is just speculation!

Answer (score 15):

The concept behind what you correctly identified as a joke is that Wolverine, as the biggest name in the X-Men franchise* has pull with the studio.  Deadpool implies that he has performed services for Wolverine (in a crass manner, of course) in return for Wolverine using his pull with the studio to make it easier for Deadpool's movie to be made.

This is a reference to the implied, rumored, and accused practices of some Hollywood executives.  Said executives would preferentially deliver roles, higher pay, and/or better present material submitted by people who had performed services (not necessarily sexual) for them.

The second level to this joke is, of course, that Wolverine (as a fictional character) does not have any actual ability to influence the development of the Deadpool movie, or to actually be serviced by Deadpool.

***The joke is now explained, which has also rendered it unfunny.  Deadpool wouldn't like that.***

*Wolverine is the most popular character in the X-Men (and associated team) comics, and the character's popularity has stretched to having three recent 'solo' or 'title' films.  There was also a study done years ago by Marvel, and they discovered that [having Wolverine on the cover of a comic lead to a significant increase in sales of that issue](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WolverinePublicity) (even when he did not appear within the issue). (Warning, TV Tropes link)

Comment: There is also the fact that there is a ongoing feud between Deadpool and Wolverine (primarily perpetuated by Deadpool of course).

Comment: And, arguably, Ryan Reynolds turn as Deadpool in Wolverine Origins is the equivalent "degrading act that eventually led to him getting his own movie."

Comment: Correction: 3 title/solo films! X-Men Origins: Wolverine, The Wolverine, and Logan

Comment: @Derek: Thanks!  Updated to reflect that.